# Why does changing the diffuse color of my model's effect change it for all models?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I want to change color of individual model in my game. But when I use

> effect.DiffuseColor = newColor

then all of models which were loaded from same model file change color too.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

you are changing the Diffusecolor in the same effect.

there is no easy way to clone a model

so the answer is before draw set the color properly for each model

```
// Draw method
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in m.Meshes)
{
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
       effect.DiffuseColor = newColor;   
    }
    mesh.Draw();    
}
```

Comment: In addition to this I would be setting the Diffuse color from an the mesh object. This way you can have a default color being applied to the effect if no Diffuse color is needed.